# Infer module name from type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-compiler-api

Say I have the following code:

```js
import { createConnection } from "mysql";

const connection = createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "admin",
  database: "project",
  password: "mypassword", // sensitive
  multipleStatements: true,
});
```

Acording to [Using the Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API), one can use a TypeChecker to infer the type of e.g. createConnection (In this case, that would be "Connection").

What I am interrested in knowing is whether the TypeChecker can tell us the module name of the file where it gets it's type ("mysql" as defined in line 1).

I can infer the filename using:

`typeProgram?.checker.getTypeAtLocation(node).type.symbol.valueDeclaration.parent.fileName`

Which in this case would return:

`"/Users/USERNAME/git/eslint-plugin-security-rules/node_modules/@types/mysql/index.d.ts"`

From here, I can traverse the filename to get the module name and this is currently my best solution as to how to approach the problem. However, I would love to know if there's a function or variable that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
const symbol = checker.getTypeAtLocation(node).symbol;

// "mysql".createConnection
typeChecker.getFullyQualifiedName(symbol);
```

Or if you don't mind depending on internal API:

```
// "mysql"
(symbol as any).parent?.escapedName;
```

Or using your other method:

```
// an actual implementation would need to be more robust than this
const decl = symbol.getDeclarations()![0];
const module = decl.parent.parent as ts.ModuleDeclaration;
console.log(module.name.getText());
```

Comment: This approach doesn't really work for me where the types can come from anywhere (e.g. NPM). Is there an alternative way to get the ImportDeclaration which imported a type to the current module? Imports can have variations like `* as module` and usage with `module.Type`, `import { Type }` or `import  { Type as Type2 }`. I would like to have the ImportDeclaration for doing further checks on symbols and types. I have the ts.TypeReferenceNode and ts.Symbol available.